# How to compile a c++ source file without passing it explicitly to the g++ compiler

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, iostream

I want to use a source file, say `foo.cpp` with other c++ projects. One way to do this is having a header file and providing the source file as command line arguments to g++. But I want to compile it once, store it somewhere, and use it simply by including the header file, just like we do with `iostream` where we don't include it as a build argument to g++.

I assume even if we build it as a custom library, still we need to provide the `.object` or equivalent file as an argument to g++ right? Whereas for `iostream`, its implementation is compiled and linked with our cpp file, although we don't mention it explicitly like `g++ foo.cpp iostream`.

For instance, consider this:

foo.h

```cpp
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

void disp();

#end
```

foo.cpp

```cpp
#include<weiostream> 

void disp()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello World";
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include "foo.h" \* I just wnat this to be like iostream and not 
 providing it as command-line argument *\

int main()
{
    disp();
    return 0;
}
```

It may be pointless to do it for this small program, but I am curious regarding the larger concept! And I am curious if `iostream` header file simply contains definitions or some mechanism to call its implementation library g++?

Comment: `we do with iostream where we dont include iostream as build argument to g++` sure we do - we're linking with libstdc++ which contains, among other things, iostream implementation

Comment: You are forgetting that `g++` links the standard library implicitly.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Thank you for the help!! So if g++ links standard libraries implicitly is it written in header file to link or has g++ being configured like that? Is there a way for custom headers to  be linked implicitly?

Comment: G++ is configured like that in standard installation, and while a lot of standard library are pure header implementations, libstdc++ is quite large. Why do you need custom library to be linked implicitly? What is wrong with explicit linking? `g++ a.c -o a -lzzz` will link library libzzz without hickup

Comment: Oh i see..! Yea explicitly linking is great , but just a random thought struck my mind if  it is possible so that I could some headers similar to standard ones implicitly linked!!!

Comment: msvc has `#pragma comment(lib,"xxx.lib")` which can do this, but gcc + clang do not seem to have this functionality